# A tricky probability question related to expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose I order integers $1,2,3,...,n$ in some random permutation, such that the integers are lined up like $a_1, a_2, .., a_n$. I choose some random index $j$ and look at the left of $a_j$. I am interested to know what is the expected number of steps I need to take to the left for me to encounter another integer greater than or equal to $a_j$? By default, if no value greater than or equal to $a_j$ exists to the left, then the number of steps taken is $j$.

My approach is the following:

For $j=1$, $E(j)=1$;
For $j=2$, there is 1 left neighbor $a_1$ which could has equal chance of either being greater or being smaller than $a_2$. So, the steps that will be taken is 1 step with probability 1/2 and 2 steps with probability 1/2. So, $E(2) = 1*1/2 + 2*1/2 = 2$.
For $j=3$, there are 2 left neighbours $a_1, a_2$. The probability of $a_2>a_3$ is 1/2 and the probability $P(a_1>a_3|a_2<a_3)=1/2*1/2=1/4$.Thus, $E(3) = 1*1/2 + 2*1/4 + 3*(1-1/2-1/4)$
Thus, in general $$E(j) = \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{i}{2^i}+j\times\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\frac{1}{2^i}\right).$$

Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: For $j=1$, $E(j)=1$. For $j=2$, $E(j)=2$, and so on, because the expectation of a constant is the constant.

Comment: @paperskilltrees I suspect $E(j)$ is supposed to be the expected number of steps rather that the expectation of $j$.  So for $j=2$ you have $E(j)$ as $\frac32$

Comment: If $j > 2$ then the probability you take exactly two steps is not $\frac1{4}$ but $\frac{1}{6}$. Consider $P(a_1>a_3>a_2) = \frac16$ while $P(a_1>a_3\mid a_2<a_3) =\frac13$

Comment: Does that mean that for $j>2$, the probability that you take exactly $n$ steps is $1/(n+1)!$?

Comment: @Henry Any non-standard notation should be explicitly introduced. Sometimes writing a question properly might help answering it (and in any case will help the efforts of others).

Comment: @titanium As far as I can see, you are only considering the case $j=n$ in your approach. Henry's comment seems to have pointed that out as well.

Comment: @titanium Have you tried to get rid of the permutation? What if you pretend that the numbers are permuted, but when thinking about the problem you really look at the unpermuted sequence $1,2,3,\dots,n$?

Comment: @titanium - no.  If $j>3$, the probability you take exactly three steps is $\frac1{12}$ and you need to work out why.  Meanwhile the probability you fail (counted as $j$ steps) is $\frac1j$.